# No errors but part of code that should display type and amount of pizzas ordered is not working

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public class PizzaExamfinalOne{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    double total2 = 0;
    String customerName = " ";
    String address = " ";
    String phoneNum ="0";
    int max = 5;
    int done = 1;
    double totalPizza = 0;
    double totalA = 0;

    int pizzaChoice =0;

    String [] pizzaType = {"Placeholder",  "Hawaian" , "Classic Italian" , "Cheese Extreme" , "Veg Delight" , "Pepperoni" , "Tomato Margherita" , "Beef & Onion" , "Super Supreme" , "Meat Lovers" , "Hot 'n Spicy" , "Italiano" , "Italian Veg"};
    double [] pizzaPrice = {0, 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 13.5 , 13.5 , 13.5 , 13.5 , 13.5};
    int [] orderDisplay = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    boolean pickup = true;
    int pickup1 = readInt("If you wish to pickup press 1 or  press 0 for delivery");
    if (pickup1 ==0){
      pickup = false;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <pizzaType.length; i++){
      System.out.println(i + " " +pizzaType[i] + " $" + pizzaPrice[i]);
    }

    while (done !=0){

      pizzaChoice = readInt ("Choose the type of pizza you wish to order");
      double pizzaQuantity = readInt ("How many " + pizzaType[pizzaChoice] + " pizzas do you wish to buy (Maximum is 5)");   

      totalPizza = totalPizza + pizzaQuantity;
      if(totalPizza > max){
        System.out.println("You cannot order more than five pizzas");
        pizzaChoice = 0;  
        pizzaQuantity = 0;
      }

      done= readInt ("Press 0 if you are done or press 1 to make another pizza order");
      double total1 = pizzaQuantity*pizzaPrice[pizzaChoice];
      total2 = total2 + total1;

    }

    if(pickup==false){
      int deliveryCost = 3;
      customerName = readString ("Please enter your full name");
      address = readString ("Please enter the Delivery address");
      phoneNum = readString ("Please enter the phone number of " + customerName);
      totalA = total2 + deliveryCost;
      System.out.println("Delivery order for " + customerName);
      System.out.println("To " + address + ", Phone number 0" + phoneNum);

    }
      else{
      customerName = readString ("Please enter your full name");
      System.out.println("Pickup order for " + customerName);
      int deliveryCost = 0;
      totalA = total2 + deliveryCost;

    }
```

My problem is here. I need to display the pizzas that the user has ordered along with the amount of pizzas ordered and I'm stuck here. there are no errors in the code it just doesnt display the following

```
    for(int i=1;i<orderDisplay.length;i++){
      if(orderDisplay[i]>0){
        System.out.println("       " + orderDisplay[i] +  " " + pizzaType[i] + " pizzas");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The total amount of your order is " + formatMoney(totalA));
  }


  public static int readInt(String prompt){
    System.out.println(prompt);
    java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);                                
    return keyboard.nextInt();
  }
  public static String readString (String prompt){
    System.out.println (prompt);
    java.util.Scanner keyboard= new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    return keyboard.nextLine();
  }

  public static String formatMoney(double phoneNum){
    java.text.NumberFormat  fmt = java.text.NumberFormat. getCurrencyInstance();
    return(fmt.format(phoneNum));
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try and debug your code? Please find out the exact spot where it starts to go wrong, otherwise it's hard to help and most here will hesitate to even try.

Comment: @Thomas well i cant find anyway to 'debug' my code (i'm using DrJava as my IDE) but i have compiled and run the program and there are no errors its just that when its supposed to display the order it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set all the array elements of orderDisplay to 0.

```
int [] orderDisplay = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

U never changed the value of orderDispaly elements and checking for value greater than 0 and u have started your loop with value 1. check the below lines.

```
 for(int i=1;i<orderDisplay.length;i++){
      if(orderDisplay[i]>0){
        System.out.println("       " + orderDisplay[i] +  " " + pizzaType[i] + " pizzas");
      }
```

Here is your answer :

```
public class PizzaExamFinalOne
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        double total2 = 0;
        String customerName = " ";
        String address = " ";
        String phoneNum ="0";
        int max = 5;
        int done = 1;
        double totalPizza = 0;
        double totalA = 0;
        int pizzaChoice =0;
        String [] pizzaType = {"Placeholder",  "Hawaian" , "Classic Italian" , "Cheese Extreme" , "Veg Delight" , "Pepperoni" , "Tomato Margherita" , "Beef & Onion" , "Super Supreme" , "Meat Lovers" , "Hot 'n Spicy" , "Italiano" , "Italian Veg"};
        double [] pizzaPrice = {0, 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 8.5 , 13.5 , 13.5 , 13.5 , 13.5 , 13.5};
        int [] orderDisplay = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        boolean pickup = true;
        int pickup1 = readInt("If you wish to pickup press 1 or  press 0 for delivery");
        if (pickup1 == 0)
        {
            pickup = false;
        }
        while (done != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <pizzaType.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " " +pizzaType[i] + " $" + pizzaPrice[i]);
            }
            pizzaChoice = readInt ("Choose the type of pizza you wish to order");
            int pizzaQuantity = readInt ("How many " + pizzaType[pizzaChoice] + " pizzas do you wish to buy (Maximum is 5)");
            totalPizza = totalPizza + pizzaQuantity;            
            if(totalPizza > max)
            {
                totalPizza = totalPizza - pizzaQuantity;
                System.out.println("You cannot order more than five pizzas");
                pizzaChoice = 0;  
                pizzaQuantity = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                orderDisplay[pizzaChoice] = pizzaQuantity;
            }
            done= readInt ("Press 0 if you are done or press 1 to make another pizza order");
            double total1 = pizzaQuantity*pizzaPrice[pizzaChoice];
            total2 = total2 + total1;
        }
        if(totalPizza > 0)
        {
            if(pickup == false)
            {
                int deliveryCost = 3;
                customerName = readString ("Please enter your full name");
                address = readString ("Please enter the Delivery address");
                phoneNum = readString ("Please enter the phone number of " + customerName);
                totalA = total2 + deliveryCost;
                System.out.println("Delivery order for " + customerName);
                System.out.println("To " + address + ", Phone number 0" + phoneNum);
            }
            else
            {
                customerName = readString ("Please enter your full name");
                System.out.println("Pickup order for " + customerName);
                int deliveryCost = 0;
                totalA = total2 + deliveryCost;
            }
            for(int i=1;i<orderDisplay.length;i++)
            {
                if(orderDisplay[i]>0)
                {
                    System.out.println("       " + orderDisplay[i] +  " " + pizzaType[i] + " pizzas");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The total amount of your order is " + formatMoney(totalA));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have not ordered anything.");
        }
    }
    public static int readInt(String prompt)
    {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);                                
        return keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    public static String readString (String prompt)
    {
        System.out.println (prompt);
        java.util.Scanner keyboard= new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        return keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    public static String formatMoney(double phoneNum)
    {
        java.text.NumberFormat  fmt = java.text.NumberFormat. getCurrencyInstance();
        return(fmt.format(phoneNum));
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason loop has been started from value 1 is that first place, that is value 0, is for placeholder and will always be 0.

Comment: so how do you suggest i fix??

Comment: In your while loop for each type of pizza customer order you have to store the number of pizza's in orderDisplay array orderDisplay[pizzaChoice] = pizzaQuantity;

Answer (score 2):

You don't add orders to your `orderDisplay` array.

You should handle it in `if(pickup==false){..}`

Comment: im very new to programming so sorry if im getting annoying but i don't  get what you mean

Comment: in your for loop, you iterate over your `orderDisplay` array, but you need to populate it with given pizza orders in the first place. In your code it's all but 0's